# jssor: Showing blank slide areas

Tags: jssor

I'm using thumbnail-navigator-with-arrows.source.html and loaded my images. The slide show has several blank image areas and the loading arrow shows in it's place, then the slide show freezes.

I have 12 images loaded. Is there an area I need to tell the script how many slides to present?

Thanks,
Jack

Comment: Resolved it on my own. Coder error - typos in the photo links, which resulted in the "loading" graphic trying to load an image that wasn't there.

Answer (score 1):

Please set $DisplayPieces to 12

```
        var options = {
            $AutoPlay: true,                                    //[Optional] Whether to auto play, to enable slideshow, this option must be set to true, default value is false
            $AutoPlayInterval: 4000,                            //[Optional] Interval (in milliseconds) to go for next slide since the previous stopped if the slider is auto playing, default value is 3000
            $SlideDuration: 500,                                //[Optional] Specifies default duration (swipe) for slide in milliseconds, default value is 500
            $DragOrientation: 3,                                //[Optional] Orientation to drag slide, 0 no drag, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 3 either, default value is 1 (Note that the $DragOrientation should be the same as $PlayOrientation when $DisplayPieces is greater than 1, or parking position is not 0)

            $ThumbnailNavigatorOptions: {
                $Class: $JssorThumbnailNavigator$,              //[Required] Class to create thumbnail navigator instance
                $ChanceToShow: 2,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always

                $Loop: 2,                                       //[Optional] Enable loop(circular) of carousel or not, 0: stop, 1: loop, 2 rewind, default value is 1
                $SpacingX: 3,                                   //[Optional] Horizontal space between each thumbnail in pixel, default value is 0
                $SpacingY: 3,                                   //[Optional] Vertical space between each thumbnail in pixel, default value is 0
                $Cols: 12,                              //[Optional] Number of pieces to display, default value is 1
                $Align: 204,                          //[Optional] The offset position to park thumbnail,

                $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
                    $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$,              //[Requried] Class to create arrow navigator instance
                    $ChanceToShow: 2,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
                    $Steps: 12                                       //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request, default value is 1
                }
            }
        };
```